# About the proof that “ a bounded and monotone sequence is convergent”

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I read a reference about the proof of  “a bounded and monotone sequence is convergent”, in a certain PDF written by a physics professor.

Details of the reference is that the proposition  “a bounded and monotone sequence is convergent” **cannot** be proved without the contradiction method.

But,I look up the proof of the theorem in other three books , This theorem is apparently not proved with indirect proof in any books.

I am very confused.
Maybe,
I think that we implicitly use reductio ad absurdum in the demonstration of the proposition.

I wish people familiar with this problem which answer.

Answer (score 5):

That proposition **can** be proved without the contradiction method.

**Proof:** Assume that $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is increasing and bounded (the case in which it is decreasing is similar). Since the set $\{a_n\,|\,n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is bounded above, it has a supremum $s$. I will prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=s$. Take $\varepsilon>0$. Then, since $s-\varepsilon<s$, $s-\varepsilon$ is *not* an upper bound of $\{a_n\,|\,n\in\mathbb{N}\}$. So, there is some natural $N$ such that $a_n>s-\varepsilon$. And if $n\geqslant N$, then $s-\varepsilon<a_N\leqslant a_n\leqslant s$. In particular,$$n\geqslant N\implies\lvert a_n-s\rvert<\varepsilon.$$

Comment: Maybe you should explicitly point out that $s$ is actually a bound to show that the sequence never exceeds $s$ and therefore never exceeds $s + \varepsilon$.

Comment: @Arthur I've edited my answer. Thank you. Concerning the part of proving that $s$ is a bound, there is nothing to prove, since, by definition, $s$ is the least upper bound.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thank you for answering.I know that the proposition can be proved without the indirect proof,The same proof is listed in three books which I read.The physics professor asserts that “The theorem cannot be proved without the contradiction method” is **really** proved. But there is the proof without using the indirect proof.So I want to know whether the assertion by the professor is right or wrong.I am sorry that what I want to say is vague.

Comment: **Of course** it is wrong. Did you read my first sentence?